# PHP and SQL - How can i select two tables and two columns

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a "simulation" from a ecommerce store, for a project.

And my idea is: When the customer tries to buy a specific product, he have to click on a link, and this link goes to a page with a submit form.

And this form, must have, automatically, the information from the product on three text boxes, and three empaty textboxes with the name of "Name, city and telephone".

So, when the user isn't logged, the text three boxes(name, city and telephone) appears empaty, but if the user is logged, all the information from the logged account, automatically appears on the textboxes.

I want to select two tables, and two ID's from the different tables

Sorry for my english, but i hope you understand:

Here my function:

```
 function buyProduct() {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `cds`";
            if(($rs=$this->bd->executarSQL($sql))){

                $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 

    $consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cds`, WHERE ID='$id' LIMIT 1");
    $productCount = mysql_num_rows($consulta); 
    if ($productCount > 0) {

                        while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))   {

                             $gravadora = $linha['gravadora'];  
                             $artista = $linha['artista'];  
                             $id = $linha['ID'];  
                             $detalhes = $linha['detalhes'];  
                             $preco = $linha['preco'];  
                             $imagem = $linha['imagem'];  
                             $categoria = $linha['categoria'];  
                            $titulo = $linha['titulo'];  

                       }

    } else {
        echo "Este produto não existe.";
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo "Lamentamos, mas ocorreu um erro na página.";
    exit();
} 

echo '<a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">Name:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="nome" style="width:220px; "></input><p>
        <a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">City:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="morada" style="width:220px;" ></input><p>
        <a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">Telephone:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="telefone" style="width:220px;"></input><p>
        <a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">Titulo do CD:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" style="width:220px;"  value="'.$titulo.'"></input><p>
        <a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">Artista:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="artista" style="width:220px;"  value="'.$artista.'"></input><p>
        <a style="font-size:20px; color: #ff00ff;">Preço:</a><p>
        <input type="text" name="preco" style="width:220px;"  value="'.$preco.'"></input><p>
<br>
         <input type="submit" class="registrar" value="Comprar CD"><p>';
         }
```

Comment: what is the second table? and why can't You use simple "join" or "left join" with "if" statement?

Comment: It seems you want to do an inner join, is that correct?

Comment: It seems you need to study SQL and PHP a little more, it will help you in your project, and a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're not being concise in your question.

The proper syntax for "simply" selecting two columns each from two tables is this:

```
SELECT `table1`.`col1`,
       `table1`.`col2`,
       `table2`.`col1`,
       `table2`.`col2`
FROM `table1`, `table2`
```

Without you giving us your table schema or your specific needs more clearly, we can't really help you with a more specific query.  Often [MySQL joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) are more appropriate than this syntax, especially if the tables [are relational](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/).

I recommend reading something [like this](http://amzn.com/1449319262).